# Calculate Population From Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, population

I must write a function that returns the summed population total in a given geographic region for a given year. It should take as input a year as an `int` and region as a `str` and should return an `int` corresponding to the population.

I am a bit stuck and not sure how to go about further. Could anyone maybe assist me? I would appreciate it.

```
def total_pop_in_region(year,region):
"""
This function returns the summed population total in a given geographic region for a given year.

Parameters:
-----------
items: (intergar, string) contains numerical and regional (string) entries.

Returns:
--------
total_pop_in_region: (dictionary) returns a summed population 

"""

pop_in_region = 1970, "South Asia"

return
```

Comment: it is an assignment

Comment: can you perhaps tell us more about how the data-frame looks like? what columns do you have? I'd guess you first have to add a region to every country if that's not already there then filter the results according to that specific region, then all you have to do is loop over the filtered results summing the values in the population column.